# Increment 1 hour on current time using Groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to increment only hour on current time.
E.g : User current time is `2017/08/28 17:27:23`
and the result I want is `Mon Aug 28 18:00:00 IST 2017` - means it only increment the hour and rest minutes and seconds should be zero.

```
def d = (new Date()).format('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss')
log.info d
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    //Add increment hour by 1
    def incre = new Date(d) + 1.hours
    log.info incre
}
```

Result i am getting : `Mon Aug 28 18:35:24 IST 2017`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Date.set(Map map)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#set(java.util.Map)) to update specific fields like `minute` or `second`. Keep in mind that this method mutates `Date` object and returns `void` so in your case you can simply add:

```
incre.set(minute: 0, second: 0)
```

after initializing `Date incre` object and it will set minutes and seconds to 0, e.g.

```
def d = (new Date()).format('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss')
log.info d
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    //Add increment hour by 1
    def incre = new Date(d) + 1.hours
    incre.set(minute: 0, second: 0)
    log.info incre
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Getting this Error -- No such field found: field java.lang.Integer hours